# Blogspot remove black line above posts

Tags: html, blogger, blogspot

Super-amatuer coder trying to create a perfect wedding blogsite. I've been pointed in the direction of this forum from here https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/blogger/XoinQAtTfOk/8Zw0SsX8AAAJ

I've removed post/page titles on my blog, but it's left a short horizontal black line still. Is there a way to remove this?

I used the following html code to remove the titles:

.post h3 {display:none !important;}

The URL is https://chrisandruthgetweddytorumble.blogspot.com/ for anyone that wants to take a closer look.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inspect the page to find the code. For example, in Chrome if you right-click and select "inspect" code will appear in the right side. When I select that shot line, I see "::before:". So, however blogspot removes that would solve your problem.[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you do `F12` and select that horizontal piece, you will get this:

[image]

You need to delete that `::before` to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You may use this [immediate before "</head>" tag]:

```
<style>
.widget.FeaturedPost .featured-post-snippet::before {
    content: "";
}
.page .widget.FeaturedPost .post-header {
    display: none !important;
    height: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
</style>
```